# Convert the AccessDB query into T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a question about `Transform` and `Pivot`. I need to convert the following Access DB query to T-SQL:

```
TRANSFORM First([UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPL Link]) AS [FirstOfRPL Link]
SELECT [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPL Link], [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Detail1
FROM [UETTDRSB39A Criteria], [Candidate Evidence records]
WHERE ((([UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Pathway) In ('Common','Electrical')))
GROUP BY [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPL Link], [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Detail1
PIVOT [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Prerequisite;
```

I tried converting the query, however, I get some errors.

```
select pt.* 
from (

SELECT [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPLLink], [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Detail1, Prerequisite

FROM [UETTDRSB39A Criteria], [CandidateEvidenceRecords]

WHERE ((([UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Pathway) In ('Common','Electrical')))

GROUP BY [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPLLink], [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Detail1
) src

pivot (FIRST(RPLLink) for src.Prerequisite in ([UEENEEE101],[UEENEEE102],[UEENEEE104],[UEENEEE105],[UEENEEE107],[UEENEEE137],
[UEENEEG006],[UEENEEG033],[UEENEEG063],[UEENEEG101],[UEENEEG102],[UEENEEG106],[UEENEEG108], [UEENEEG109],
[UEENEEK142],[UETTDREL16A],[UETTDRIS67A],[UETTDRSB39A])) pt;
```

The error reads 'first is not an aggregate function'. However, when I enter:

```
select pt.* 
from (
SELECT [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPLLink], [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Detail1, Prerequisite

FROM [UETTDRSB39A Criteria], [CandidateEvidenceRecords]

WHERE ((([UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Pathway) In ('Common','Electrical')))

GROUP BY [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].[RPLLink], [UETTDRSB39A Criteria].Detail1
) src

pivot (top 1 (RPLLink) for src.Prerequisite in ([UEENEEE101],[UEENEEE102],[UEENEEE104],[UEENEEE105],[UEENEEE107],[UEENEEE137],
[UEENEEG006],[UEENEEG033],[UEENEEG063],[UEENEEG101],[UEENEEG102],[UEENEEG106],[UEENEEG108], [UEENEEG109], [UEENEEK142],[UETTDREL16A],[UETTDRIS67A],[UETTDRSB39A])) pt;
```

The table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UETTDRSB39A Criteria](
[UoC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AncestorLevel] [int] NULL,
[Pathway] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Prerequisite] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Title] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Descriptor] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[UoCType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Summary] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[Ref] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Detail] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[Type1] [nvarchar](800) NULL,
[RPLType] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[RPLPreferred] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
[RPLLink] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Detail1] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CandidateEvidenceRecords](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[EvidenceID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Candidate] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
[EvidenceType] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[UoC] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Evidence] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
[DateOfIssue] [date] NULL,
[DateOfExpiry] [date] NULL,
[Issuer] [nvarchar](1500) NULL,
[CertificateNumber] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Confirmed] [bit] NULL,
[ConfirmedBy] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[ConfirmedDate] [date] NULL
)
```

---

[Access Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiVgm.png)

[SQL Query Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovgHE.png)

[SQL Query Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02NEl.png)

---

It still does not work.
Looking forward to your response.

Thank you

Comment: could you also add table schemas ( [UETTDRSB39A Criteria], [Candidate Evidence records], [RPLEvidence options] ), relation betwen tables and expected result?

Comment: Hi Serkan, I have added the table schemas and the required screenshots. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Max()` instead of `First()`, if there's only one value anyway.

If there are multiple values, and you want the first value ordered by a certain key, use a subquery to filter out the other values and then use `Max()`

Comment: Hi Erik, Thanks for your response. I tried using max (since each cell has just one value). However, it is not giving me the same output as the access DB.

Comment: Well, then provide sample data, output in Access, and output in SQL server, so we can see what's going wrong

Comment: First is a really unreliable operator and should be top of the list to be removed from Access imho... I would actually suspect that the SQL query is accurate and that your Access query is giving you incorrect results. Have a read here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=146203&postcount=4 for an example and explanation.

Comment: Note that, if desired, I could implement First() in SQL server as a custom aggregate, and it would likely behave even less consistent than First() in Access

Comment: Hi Erik, I have added the screenshots of the output. PFA.

Comment: Hi Minty, thank you for your response. However, I am getting a NULL value in each cell, which I believe is not the desired output. I reckon there is something wrong with the SQL Query itself.